# Custom exception maximum message length?

Tags: apex, exception

What is the maximum length of the message of a custom exception?

```
class CustomException extends Exception{}

public static void throwException(){
     String message = 'lots of text........';
     if(true) throw new CustomException(message);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message will work and throw for any message length up to and including 6 million characters. Beyond that, instead of getting `CustomException`, you will get a governor exception instead:

> System.LimitException: String is too long.

However, once you hit 1 million characters, you will start seeing truncation and the following appended to the end:

> *********** MAXIMUM ApexException MESSAGE SIZE REACHED **************

And yes there are a different number of asterisks before versus after the message.